# adding columns into existing sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing sql command as variable, and I want to add some generated/variable columns to it, tried full join without condition but not successful,

sql is dynamically changing will be provided as an input to command. some examples what it could be and answer should work for all.

```
sql = 'SELECT X FROM Y WHERE A = 1'
sql = '(SELECT X FROM F WHERE A = 2)'
sql = 'SELECT X FROM G WHERE B = (SELECT D FROM F WHERE B = 5)'
sql = 'SELECT X FROM H WHERE G = 0'
sql = 'SELECT X FROM P WHERE W = 2'
sql = 'SELECT X FROM Z WHERE J = 9'


SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE(), sql

INSERT INTO Foo (A, B ,C) SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE(), sql
```

Sample result,

[image]

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: I am using mssql

Comment: Mysql does not support GetDate(), NewID() . its should be SQL Server

Comment: good luck... it's a long way to go

Comment: Can you provide a fully working simplified example of what you have so far. `sql = (SELECT X FROM Y) -- this is dynamic variable / input` is not valid SQL. I (looks like I am not the only one) don't understand what you are trying to say here.

Comment: It is very simple, sql command is not predefined not static. It will be provided as input. It will change everytime. so you shouldn't hard code sample I gave, to clear confusion I added many different samples.

Comment: I don't understand. You have dynamic input, so it could be anything (Hi SQL Injection) and you want to add generated / variable columns to that input? You basically need to write something that parses SQL so it can account for every conceivable form before you can dynamically add columns. If I understand your requirement correctly (it's not explained very well) then to allow for every type of valid SQL input this is not trivial. What is the relationship between table `Foo` which has three columns, and your first sample select statement which has one column of indeterminate data type?

Comment: I will give a sql query that lists some email and It will generate Foo rows for each email. I will use this functionality, not the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic query here.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT X FROM Y WHERE A = 1' -- initial input
SET @sql = 'SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE(), ' + LTRIM((SUBSTRING(@sql, 7, LEN(@sql) - 6)))
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO Foo (A, B, C) ' + @sql 

--EXEC(@sql)
print @sql
```

Output (executable query):

```
INSERT INTO Foo (A, B, C) SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE(), X FROM Y WHERE A = 1
```

Comment: you are cutting off "SELECT" and merging as text, is a solution. probably will work but I am not very comfortable with text manipulating. It might cause unwanted/unexpected results in complicated sql queries. I will wait for a better solution, but this is only valid answer so far. thank you very much.

Comment: *It might cause unwanted/unexpected results in complicated sql queries* - It should not. That's the purpose I didn't replace `SELECT`, only stripped the one that's at the beginning of original query. I don't see any other way to do this without text manipulation and dynamic query. BTW question is on hold so you cannot expect more answers. :-|

Comment: you could understand the question, but some idiots couldn't sent the topic to off topic because of their stupidity even I did everything to make them understand my topic is blocked. Its very simple if someone else can understand It is your problem if you can't, not the OPs. these people drive me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work.

```
INSERT INTO Foo (A, B ,C) 
SELECT NEWID(),GETDATE(), X FROM Y
```

Dynamic query:-

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)= 'select val from sumavg'

SET @sql=REPLACE(@sql,'select','select GETDATE(), NEWID(),')
EXEC(@sql )
```

Comment: sql is coming as variable, I cant manipulate that, you should write a command to wrap it.

Comment: Is sql multi value variable or single ? this is how you insert multiple values @Mert

Comment: sql returns multiple results

Comment: sql is dynamic command, what I gave is just a sample, you can't hard code it.

Comment: @Mert I can help you if you provide the dynamic query.

Comment: how can I provide something dynamic man :) it is dynamic, random sql command should work with it.

Comment: I mean if you want to store multiple values in SQL variable - the type should be table. try to save them in a temp table (SQL can be temp table) and then select & insert accordingly.

Comment: can you give me sample of your solution which would work with any of sample sql queries.

Comment: @Mert  Try the updated answer :)

Comment: this is doing samething with niksoftengs. where is temp table and stuff?

Comment: @Mert I didn't see that solution . I though this was easy one than temp table.

Comment: easy but dangerous, if dynamic sql has more then one select for example.